How to add lazily loaded modules in angular inside mat sidenav content?
In angular app how to add lazily loaded modules/rotes inside mat sidenav content?

You can use angular-modules for your sidenav content which can be easil lazy loaded and each module can have its own path/paths.
Sample execution might look like this:
// app-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'module1',
        loadChildren: () => import('./module1/module1.module').then(m => m.Module1Module)
      },
      {
        path: 'module2',
        loadChildren: () => import('./module2/module2.module').then(m => m.Module2Module)
      }
      // Add more lazy-loaded modules as needed
    ]
  }
];

Then in the HTML, you can load these routes:
<!-- main-layout.component.html -->
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
    <!-- Sidenav content -->
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/module1">Module 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="/module2">Module 2</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <!-- This is where your lazy-loaded content will appear -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>

Your each module might be different and can have different routes and those can be defined in your module's each routing section. Like this:
// module1.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Module1Component } from './module1.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: Module1Component }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [Module1Component],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class Module1Module { }

Just be sure that you are loading the right modules in the right section and this should work.

When I implemented this on the default route which is shown in the code I was able to see sidenav component twice. Any idea on that? It seems due to the router outlet it is showing the same component twice.
My main component is the App Component. Tried the same with some other components but got the same result.

Make sure if you are having any of the child components, those should not be added in any template => Direct module will take care of it. Since you already have router-outlet, the component to load will be taken care of. You again need not add <child-1-from-module-1> like this. Please try that.
